# How can know driver of TV tuner?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers

I have TV tuner card which I bought it since 2005 and I lost its box & CD driver.
I can't remember its type, there is no information in the card itself except that I can read `conaxent` in a chip and the `barcode`.

Any idea about how I can install the driver?
I have windows XP and it detects the card but it does not know what it is!

Comment: I would be highly surprised if there was indeed no label or information on the card. Unfortunately Conaxent is a general mfg that provides to multiple vendors, so while you could search for a generic driver, you would be best off finding the make and model. Try looking closely at the board for small writing or for nearly-camouflaged writing that blends into the board (on *both* sides). Failing that, try posting a clear, high-res photo (no flash-washout) of both sides so that we can take a look for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the hardware ID of the device and look it up with Bing or Google.

Hold the Windows button and press R, type devmgmt.msc and hit ENTER, find your device - it will show in yellow since you do not have the driver.   Right click and select Properties.  Select the "Details" tab and select "Hardware IDs" from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Conexant is mentioned here if that's any help:

http://forums.pcpitstop.com/index.php?/topic/136619-conexant-tv-tuner/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `lspci` command to see what devices are plugged into your PCI slots.  This should give you the branding string for the device.  You can use `lspci -n` to get the vendor id and device id which will help you figure out what driver you might need.

Comment: Did you bother to look at the tags or read the question? They clearly said *Windows XP*, and there is [no known Windows port/version](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1110172) [of that command](http://superuser.com/questions/97238/windows-equivalent-for-lspci).

Comment: You're right, I missed that.  However, I would think that in Windows you can get similar information by going into the Device Manager and looking at the Properties on the device.  Or boot up a Linux Live CD on the machine and use the Linux tools to inspect the hardware.

Comment: Shannon, you're right - or the OP could run a Linux live CD and use the command.

Comment: Does it really sound to you guys like the OA is the type to use Linux? :roll: